# How to make something a square using only percentage measurements

Tags: html, css, percentage

I'm writing a game of pong in JavaScript, and I need the ball to be a square for obvious reasons. I'm using percentage measurements so the game works on all resolutions, but I was wondering how to make the ball a square using these.

```
#ball{
  position: absolute;
  height: 1.5%;
  width: 1.5%;
  background-color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -12.5px;
  margin-left: -12.5px;
}
```

Obviously 1.5% of the width is a lot more than 1.5% of the height. Does anyone know how to make these two the same in pixels, without sacrificing flexibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `height`, you can use percentage `padding-bottom` (or `padding-top`):

```css
#ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3.5%;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -12.5px;
  margin-left: -12.5px;
  padding-bottom: 3.5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="ball"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use viewport units `vh` or `vw` where size depends on window size so it will be flexible relative to window size but not parent element size.

```css
.square {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
#ball {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1.5%;
    width: 1.5%;
    max-height: 1.5%;
    max-width: 1.5%;
    background-color: #d84343;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -12.5px;
    margin-left: -12.5px;
    padding: 38px 30px;
}
```

**Or use in pixel**

```
#ball {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: #d84343;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -12.5px;
    margin-left: -12.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using percentages, I would recommend to use rem units, which is responsive as well.

```css
#ball {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="ball"></div>
```